# По какому принципу формируются идентификаторы в Android?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Например, есть идентификаторы **@+id/listView1** и **[@android](/users/8445/android):id/list**

Как они читаются/расшифровываются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий формат ссылки такой: `@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>`

**@+id/listView1** означает что создается идентификатор с именем **listView1** в пространстве разрабатываемого приложения. Обращаться к нему можно как **[@id](/users/3123/idanil)/listView1**

**[@android](/users/8445/android):id/list** означает ссылку на идентификатор с именем **list** в пространстве **android**.

Comment: Правильно) Сам спросил - сам ответил. Добавлю, что приложение также может создавать свое пространство имен для идентификаторов и ресурсов, с помощью специально заданного стиля.